# Trying to copy the contents of a website to a string for analysis

Tags: mql5

so I am writing a code for a news filter expert for the mt5 platform. This is how the code is supposed to work, download the html page, copy the contents of the page onto a string, and then use the string for analysis.

So far I have managed to successfully download the html page
The main problem is now copying the contents of the html page onto the string to help in my analysis. Kindly help

`int filehandle2=FileOpen("news-log.html",FILE_READ|FILE_BIN); TXT=FileReadString(filehandle2,ArraySize(result));`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, it should work.

```
string str;
int file_handle=FileOpen("news-log.html",FILE_READ|FILE_BIN|FILE_ANSI);
if(file_handle!=INVALID_HANDLE)
{
      str=FileReadString(file_handle,int(FileSize(file_handle)));
      FileClose(file_handle);
}
else PrintFormat("Failed to open %s file, Error code = %d","news-log.html",GetLastError());
```

Comment: Hello thank you for the solution, its now copying but not the whole file, its copying like 1/4 of the file, is there a limit to the length of a string?

Comment: Not as far as I am aware. Can you post a copy of your file?

Comment: Okay let me do that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67922487/trying-to-create-a-news-expert-using-data-from-investing-com

Comment: I restructured my question there, looking forward to your reply, thank you so much