# Trying to create a news expert using data from investing.com

Tags: mql5, mql

find the code attached below, so the ReadCBOE function reads information from investing.com and saves it to string str, Update news function then analyzes the information obtained from ReadCBOE and stores it into relevant arrays, the code is running without any errors just cant figure out why information is not being stored correctly into the arrays. ps the same code works perfectly on mt4

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------+     
string ReadCBOE()
      {
       string cookie=NULL,headers;
       char post[],result[];     string TXT="";
       int res;
       string str;
    
       string google_url="http://ec.forexprostools.com/?columns=exc_currency,exc_importance&importance=1,2,3&calType=week&timeZone=15&lang=1";
       ResetLastError();
       int timeout=5000; 
       res=WebRequest("GET",google_url,cookie,NULL,timeout,post,0,result,headers);
       if(res==-1)
         {
          Print("WebRequest error, err.code  =",GetLastError());
          MessageBox("You must add the address 'http://ec.forexprostools.com/' in the list of allowed URL tab 'Advisors' "," Error ",MB_ICONINFORMATION);
         }
       else
         {
          int filehandle=FileOpen("news-log.html",FILE_WRITE|FILE_BIN|FILE_ANSI);
          if(filehandle!=INVALID_HANDLE)
            {
             FileWriteArray(filehandle,result,0,ArraySize(result));
             FileClose(filehandle);
             
             //------
             int file_handle=FileOpen("news-log.html",FILE_READ|FILE_BIN|FILE_ANSI);
             if(file_handle!=INVALID_HANDLE)
                {
                   str=FileReadString(file_handle,int(FileSize(file_handle)));
                   FileClose(file_handle);
                }
             else PrintFormat("Failed to open %s file, Error code = %d","news-log.html",GetLastError());
            }
         }
       return(str);
       }
    
        //-------------------------------------------------------+ 
           void UpdateNews()
              {
               string TEXT=ReadCBOE();      
               int sh = StringFind(TEXT,"pageStartAt>")+12;
               int sh2= StringFind(TEXT,"</tbody>");
               TEXT=StringSubstr(TEXT,sh,sh2-sh);
               sh=0;
               while(!IsStopped())
                 {
                  sh = StringFind(TEXT,"event_timestamp",sh)+17;
                  sh2= StringFind(TEXT,"onclick",sh)-2;
                  if(sh<17 || sh2<0)break;
                  NewsArr[0][NomNews]=StringSubstr(TEXT,sh,sh2-sh);
            
                  sh = StringFind(TEXT,"flagCur",sh)+10;
                  sh2= sh+3;
                  if(sh<10 || sh2<3)break;
                  NewsArr[1][NomNews]=StringSubstr(TEXT,sh,sh2-sh);
                  
                  sh = StringFind(TEXT,"title",sh)+7;
                  sh2= StringFind(TEXT,"Volatility",sh)-1;
                  if(sh<7 || sh2<0)break;
                  NewsArr[2][NomNews]=StringSubstr(TEXT,sh,sh2-sh);
                  if(StringFind(NewsArr[2][NomNews],"High")>=0 && !HighNews)continue;Print("Found");
                  if(StringFind(NewsArr[2][NomNews],"Moderate")>=0 && !MidleNews)continue;
                  if(StringFind(NewsArr[2][NomNews],"Low")>=0 && !LowNews)continue;
            
                  sh=StringFind(TEXT,"left event",sh)+12;
                  int sh1=StringFind(TEXT,"Speaks",sh);
                  sh2=StringFind(TEXT,"<",sh);
                  if(sh<12 || sh2<0)break;
                  if(sh1<0 || sh1>sh2)NewsArr[3][NomNews]=StringSubstr(TEXT,sh,sh2-sh);
                  else NewsArr[3][NomNews]=StringSubstr(TEXT,sh,sh1-sh);
            
                  NomNews++;
                  if(NomNews==300)break;
                 }
              }
```

Comment: @PaulB I reframed the question here hope this is clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code which should work for larger strings.

```
string ReadCBOE()
{
   string cookie=NULL,headers;
   char post[],result[];     string TXT="";
   int res;
   string str;

   string google_url="http://ec.forexprostools.com/?columns=exc_currency,exc_importance&importance=1,2,3&calType=week&timeZone=15&lang=1";
   ResetLastError();
   int timeout=5000; 
   res=WebRequest("GET",google_url,cookie,NULL,timeout,post,0,result,headers);
   if(res==-1)
   {
      Print("WebRequest error, err.code  =",GetLastError());
      MessageBox("You must add the address 'http://ec.forexprostools.com/' in the list of allowed URL tab 'Advisors' "," Error ",MB_ICONINFORMATION);
   }
   else
   {
      int filehandle=FileOpen("news-log.html",FILE_WRITE|FILE_BIN|FILE_ANSI);
      if(filehandle!=INVALID_HANDLE)
      {
         FileWriteArray(filehandle,result,0,ArraySize(result));
         FileClose(filehandle);
         //------
         int file_handle=FileOpen("news-log.html",FILE_READ|FILE_BIN|FILE_ANSI);
         if(file_handle!=INVALID_HANDLE)
         {
            do
            {
               ResetLastError();
               string Largestr=FileReadString(file_handle,4000);
               if(GetLastError()!=0) break;
               StringConcatenate(str,str,Largestr);
            }
            while(GetLastError()==0 && !FileIsEnding(file_handle));
            FileClose(file_handle);
         }
         else PrintFormat("Failed to open %s file, Error code = %d","news-log.html",GetLastError());
      }
   }
return(str);
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the answer, the function is returning an empty string, str only has a value inside the loop, if I try to print it outside the loop its prints an empty string

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem

Comment: How do I mark it as answered, I am new in stack overflow

Comment: Please see the following instructions [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), essentially, you click on the check mark beside the answer top left.

Comment: Feel free to contact me, check my profile

Comment: sent you an email at sales@bespokecoding.co.uk

Comment: Hey I have been using your solution for a while its been okay, but recently I am getting this error "one leaked string left", I have tried to check where it might arise from at no avail, any ideas?